# Scripts not loading after loading and navigating new page using (Barba.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, barbajs

**HERE THE PROBLEM:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMOlF.gif

Everything is working fine on my index.html. On the first .onload page all the images are draggable and all over the page. However, when **I WENT TO THE PAGE ABOUT.html AND GO BACK TO THE INDEX.html** my script look like isn't working anymore and I can see only one image that is not even draggable anymore.

my project here:
https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg

**HOW DO I FIX ISSUE? COULD SOMEBODY HELP ME TO FIX MY CODE?**

```
var winWidth = window.innerWidth,
    winHeight = window.innerHeight,
    threeWinHeight = winHeight*3;

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  winHeight = window.innerHeight,
  twiceWinHeight = winHeight*2;
});


$('.shape').each(function(){
  var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*1300),

      //BE CAREFUL 7000px is less then total body height or  CAUSING OVERFLOW
      leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * winWidth);
  $(this).css('top', topPos + 'px');
  $(this).css('left', leftPos + 'px');
});




Draggable.create('.shape', {
  //type:"rotation",
  bounds: '.section-2',
  edgeResistance:0.65,
  throwProps:true,
});



var number = Math.floor((Math.random() *15) + 2);
var number2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 0) + -15);
var number3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 0) + 15);
var number4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 0) + 6);
$(".shape--circle").css("transform", "rotate(" + number2 + "deg)");
$(".shape--square").css("transform", "rotate(" + number3 + "deg)");
$(".shape--circle-2").css("transform", "rotate(" + number4 + "deg)");
```

I try adding the following JS code in my main.js file inside barba.init function but did not work:

``````
  views: [{
        namespace: 'home-section',
        beforeEnter({ next }) {

        // load  script

        let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js'; 
script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/utils/Draggable.min.js';
script.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ThrowPropsPlugin.min.js'; // location of your draggable js file that is responsible for that image loading and dragging functionality

        next.container.appendChild(script);
        }, 
    }],

`````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMOlF.gif
``````

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what barba can do before entering after the transition that leads you to the new page.

For example, if you want to execute a script or just a piece of code to the next transition you can use this.

```js
barba.init({
  views: [{
    namespace: 'index',
    beforeLeave(data) {
      // do something before leaving the current `index` namespace
    }
  }, {
    namespace: 'contact',
    beforeEnter(data) {
      // do something before entering the `contact` namespace
    }
  }]
});
```

you can find the 'namespace' tag on every single HTML doc that you create and use barba.